# Function to select from table2 if no record found in table1?

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I would like to write a function/procedure in Postgres with 2 SELECT statements. First I select from table1 and if there is no record matching in `table1` then perform the same SELECT on `table2`. E.g.

```
function getRecord(String: inValue){
  If (select col1, col2 from table1 where col3=inValue) then
    return the row (with col1 and col2);
  else
    return select col1, col2 from TABLE2 where col3=inValue;
}
```

Is it possible to have a function like this in PostgreSQL (ver 9.1 and above)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need a function, just the query. But here goes:

#### PL/pgSQL function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_record(_value text)
  RETURNS TABLE(col1 int, col2 text) AS  -- replace with actual columns / types
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col3 = _value;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
   SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2 WHERE col3 = _value;
END IF;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- You can use the [special variable `FOUND`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) to check.
- This can return any number of rows, the second query is called if the first does not return anything.

#### SQL function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_record(_value text)
  RETURNS TABLE(col1 int, col2 text) AS  -- replace with actual columns / types
$func$

SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col3 = _value
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2 WHERE col3 = _value
LIMIT  1;

$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

- **If** the parameter is on a unique column and a **single row is guaranteed**.
- In older versions you need to use positional references for parameters in SQL functions. i.e.: `$1` instead of `_value` in the body. (You can still [name the parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS) in the function header, which is useful for documentation and calling with named parameters.)
- Without parentheses the `LIMIT 1` applies to the whole of the query, not just the last leg. Without `ORDER BY`! in the outer query Postgres calls each `SELECT` until enough rows are returned to satisfy the `LIMIT` clause. If you run `ANALYZE` for the query you will see "never executed" for remaining legs of the `UNION` query.

Related answers:

- [Way to try multiple SELECTs till a result is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339715/way-to-try-multiple-selects-till-a-result-is-available/14365613#14365613)
- [PostgreSQL combine multiple select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828772/postgresql-combine-multiple-select-statements/11833128#11833128)

Comment: Erwin thanks so much. I think this is what I need. Also the select query must return only on record either found in table1 or in table2 so I have LIMIT=1. THANKS A MILLION for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Might be able to do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.col1, b.col1) AS col1
      ,COALESCE(a.col2, b.col2) AS col2
  FROM table1 a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS b ON (a.col3 = inValue AND b.col3 = a.col3)
```

This assumes col1 and col2 are not nullable. Might also be able to approach it with something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2
  FROM ( SELECT col1, col2, 1 AS ordering
           FROM table1
           WHERE col3 = inValue
         UNION
         SELECT col1, col2, 2 AS ordering
           FROM table2
           WHERE col3 = inValue
       ) x
   ORDER BY ordering
   LIMIT 1;
```

If you really want to do it in a stored procedure, you can `SELECT ... INTO` local variables from table1 and then check `IF NOT FOUND THEN` to see if you need to query the other table. Then return the row created from the local variables.  See example mid-way down this page http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html.

Comment: Great help Glenn. Thanks. I will try both Erwin's and your suggestions and see which one is faster (Note: table1 and table2 are rather large and I need to optimize these selects - I had put this code in my Java application as separate selects statements but they seem to take a none trivial time to execute - this is why I am looking for a solution to put them in a postgres function/procedure so that I only make one jdbc call to the db instead of 2 as in the current code) - I will test and see if I have some speed improvement. Tx a lot.