# Randomly select fields where few condition met

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, ms-access

Here is the table-

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | letters | status |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | A       |      0 |
|  2 | B       |      1 |
|  3 | C       |      0 |
|  4 | D       |      0 |
|  5 | E       |      1 |
|  6 | F       |      1 |
|  7 | G       |      0 |
|  8 | H       |      0 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Its need to finds records with the conditions below-

1. select letters with `LIMIT 3`
2. `ORDER` is `RAND()`
3. `status true or false` **both need to present** but at-least a presents of
   letters with `status TRUE` but not more then `2`

Desire results could be as-

```
+---------+--------+
| letters | status |
+---------+--------+
| B       |      1 |
| E       |      1 |
| H       |      0 |
+---------+--------+

+---------+--------+
| letters | status |
+---------+--------+
| C       |      0 |
| E       |      1 |
| H       |      0 |
+---------+--------+
```

**But not as-**

```
+---------+--------+
| letters | status |
+---------+--------+
| C       |      0 |
| G       |      0 |
| H       |      0 |
+---------+--------+

+---------+--------+
| letters | status |
+---------+--------+
| B       |      1 |
| E       |      1 |
| F       |      1 |
+---------+--------+
```

Anyone please help.

Comment: Please edit your question. Your condition 3 isn't clear. It sounds like you need to select three randomly chosen rows from among the rows with a TRUE status. Is that correct?

Comment: What does _at least a presents of letters_ mean? That makes no sense in English.

Comment: I Edited my question.. Anyone please check.. I'm currently doing this with PHP but looking for a easy solution on mysql that will save few queries..

Comment: MySQL? Then why is this tagged PostgreSQL and MS-Access?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think its a database related question.. Is there any solution on PostgreSQL way?

Comment: Of course there is. But what good would that be if you are using MySQL?

Comment: I could study on that solution and try to find solution similar solution against MySQL..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in **Postgres** as requested in the comments.

Assuming `status` to be `NOT NULL`.
Assuming at least one row with `status` `FALSE` and one with `status` `TRUE` exist at all times.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   (
   SELECT id, letters, status
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  status       -- 1 row with status true
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT id, letters, status
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  NOT status   -- 1 row with status false
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT  1
   )
   )
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL              -- add another random row
(
SELECT id, letters, status
FROM   tbl
LEFT   JOIN cte c USING (id)
WHERE  c.id IS NULL    -- don't select row twice
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  1
)
ORDER BY random();     -- order 3 rows randomly
```

MySQL does *not* supports [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html).
All parentheses are necessary. Details:

- [PostgreSQL combine multiple select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828772/postgresql-combine-multiple-select-statements/11833128#11833128)

This is *not very efficient* for big tables. For better performance consider this related answer:

- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)

If status `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not extremely unbalanced, I would write a plpgsql function that loops through the randomly sorted table (or selection [like in the the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)) until I have three rows with at least one of each status. Would be much faster.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. vote up.. I read an article tells that MySQL do not support CTEs but alternatives is to use `TEMPORARY tables` which will very inefficient for me. I tried (SELECT * 
FROM `test`
order by rand()
limit 2)
union (
select * 
from test
where status=1 
order by rand()
limit 1) on MySQL but it sometimes return 2 results.. Hoping someone lead me to a proper solution..