# How to make conditional LIMIT in SELECT query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, sql-limit

I want to make conditional `order by` with `limit` and `offset`.
If the count is 1 then I want the latest date otherwise I want latest but one record. I was trying the below query,

*If the count of a select query is 1 then,*

```
Select * from table_name
ORDER BY date_column LIMIT 1;
```

*Otherwise,*

```
Select * from table_name
ORDER BY date_column LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

Is there any other way to implement the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from (
    Select * from table_name
    ORDER BY date_column LIMIT 2
 ) as foo ORDER BY date_column DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that is closest to your current code is to wrap it in a `CASE WHEN` statement. If you see it as `CASE WHEN (1) THEN (2) ELSE (3)`, the logic speaks for itself. (2) is executed if (1) is true, else (3) is executed.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE CASE WHEN (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table_name t
  ) > 1 THEN date_column = (
    SELECT date_column
    FROM table_name t
    ORDER BY date_column LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
  ) ELSE date_column = (
    SELECT date_column
    FROM table_name t
    ORDER BY date_column LIMIT 1
  )
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(order by date_column) rn,
        count(*) over() cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 2 or cnt = 1
```

Comment: Note: DESC (last but one)

Comment: @wildplasser: yes I asked myself the same question - the description says so, but the queries in the question show otherwise...

Comment: Agreed, the discription is vague.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
(SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date_column OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date_column LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 1
```

If there are two or more qualifying rows, the second `SELECT` will be *never executed* (you can see that in the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`). So, typically, this is the fastest possible way.

`LIMIT 1` in the subqueries is logically redundant, but it helps Postgres to chose the most efficient query plan.

See:

- [Select next or first row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/286600/3684)
- [Combine multiple SELECT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828772/combine-multiple-select-statements/11833128#11833128)
- [Way to try multiple SELECTs till a result is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339715/way-to-try-multiple-selects-till-a-result-is-available/14365613#14365613)