# Selecting a time range, but include the row before the range starts

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE balance (
  confirmed_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  value BIGINT
);
```

I want to select all rows where `confirmed_at` is between `start` and `end`, however, I would also like the row that exists right before the time range. That way if there are no rows between the range, I still know the last value that was entered.

Is there a way to do this in a single query?

Comment: Update your post with sample input tables and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT *
FROM   balance
WHERE  confirmed_at BETWEEN $start AND $end
ORDER  BY confirmed_at DESC  -- optional
)
UNION ALL
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT *
FROM   balance
WHERE  confirmed_at < $start
ORDER  BY confirmed_at DESC
LIMIT  1
);
```

You need additional `ORDER BY` items to get a deterministic pick, since `confirmed_at` is not `UNIQUE`. (Or you are OK with an arbitrary pick as is.)

If the table is not trivially small, be sure to have an index on `(confirmed_at)`.

Parentheses are required  to apply `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` locally. See:

- [Combine multiple SELECT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828772/combine-multiple-select-statements/11833128#11833128)