# Query stops parallelizing when adding LIMIT or ROW_NUMBER

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance, postgresql-parallel-query

I have 20 tables with identical structure, and I need to aggregate the results.

I'm using `UNION ALL` to collect the results, in the following structure:

```
SELECT something, SUM(total) AS overall_total
FROM (
  SELECT something, SUM(something_else) AS total
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY something

  UNION ALL
  SELECT something, SUM(something_else) AS total
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY something

  UNION ALL
  ...

  ) AS X
GROUP BY something
ORDER BY overall_total DESC
LIMIT 10
```

In this case the DB uses `Parallel Append` with multiple workers, which is very fast.

However, each table returns a large amount of data so aggregation is slow.

To improve performance, I want to limit the number of rows returned from each table to the top 100 results only, since the overall will always rely on those.

I tried using either `LIMIT` or `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` to retrieve only the top rows from each table:

```
SELECT something, SUM(something_else) AS total
FROM table2
GROUP BY something
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 100

SELECT something, SUM(something_else) AS total, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as r
FROM table2
WHERE r <= 100
GROUP BY something
ORDER BY total DESC
```

But now the plan never uses Parallel Append, so data fetch is very slow and overall performance is worse.
Can't get the parallel plan even using flags like:

```
set force_parallel_mode = on;
set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 10;
set parallel_setup_cost = 0;
set parallel_tuple_cost = 0;
```

Reading PostgreSQL documentation, parallelization can't be done when using unsafe operations. But it didn't mention `LIMIT` and `ROW_NUMBER` as being unsafe.

Comment: please show actual plans.

Answer (score 3):

#### Why?

I can reproduce the issue. As soon as I add a `LIMIT` clause to one of the `SELECT` terms of the `UNION ALL`, the parallel plan goes away, even with `set force_parallel_mode = on;`.

Maybe it's connected to [this comment in the source code](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/allpaths_8c.html#ac627277846b882c44b54a18145e5364a):

```
      * We can't push sub-select containing LIMIT/OFFSET to workers as
      * there is no guarantee that the row order will be fully
      * deterministic, and applying LIMIT/OFFSET will lead to
      * inconsistent results at the top-level.  (In some cases, where
      * the result is ordered, we could relax this restriction.  But it
      * doesn't currently seem worth expending extra effort to do so.)
```

But I am not entirely sure. This applies to "subquery in FROM". But it would seem it shouldn't keep Postgres from scheduling parallel workers for whole subqueries in `UNION ALL` in a `Parallel Append` node. Maybe just a shortcoming in current Postgres 15?

#### Test case

```sql
SELECT something, sum(total) AS overall_total
FROM  (
   (  -- !
   SELECT something, sum(something_else) AS total
   FROM   table1
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  100
   )  -- !

   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT something, SUM(something_else)
   FROM   table2
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST, 1
   LIMIT  100
   )

   --  ... more?
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST, 1
LIMIT  10;
```

See:

- [Combine multiple SELECT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828772/combine-multiple-select-statements/11833128#11833128)

You may or may not need / want `NULLS LAST`:

- [Sort NULL values to the end of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621205/sort-null-values-to-the-end-of-a-table/7622046#7622046)

I made the sort order deterministic by adding `something` as second `ORDER BY` item. Else, repeated calls might get you different results.

### Workaround

We can work around the limitation by encapsulating each root query in a **function with a `PARALLEL SAFE` label**:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION public.f_top_sums(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS TABLE (
     something int  -- adjust type to your case!
   , total bigint   -- adjust type to your case!
  )
  LANGUAGE plpgsql PARALLEL SAFE ROWS 100 COST 1000000 AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
      '
      SELECT something, sum(something_else) AS total
      FROM   %s
      GROUP  BY 1
      ORDER  BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST, 1
      LIMIT  100
      '
    , _tbl);
END   
$func$;
```

I chose a generic function with dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE`, passing table names safely. If you are unfamiliar, here is more about the basics:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

I also declared `ROWS 100` (because we know that) and, more importantly, `COST 1000000` to make the query planner consider a parallel plan. You may want to fiddle with the `COST` setting to influence the query plan ...

You can also write one simple SQL function for each table instead.

Either way, this now allows parallel plans:

```sql
SELECT something, SUM(total) AS overall_total
FROM  (
   SELECT * FROM public.f_top_sums('public.table1')
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM public.f_top_sums('public.table2')
   --  more ...
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  10;
```

---

**Aside**, your second attempt with the window function `row_number()` is illegal syntax. You cannot reference the output column `r` in the `WHERE` clause. You would need a subquery to make it work. But a single subquery level would suffice, as you can wrap the window function around the aggregate function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT something, sum(something_else) AS total
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY sum(something_else) DESC NULLS LAST) AS r
   FROM   table2
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
WHERE  r <= 100
```

That said, the first approach with `LIMIT` version is simpler and faster.

Comment: Internally, `UNION` or `UNION ALL` is always parsed as an "append" of subqueries, which ate later "pulled up" (see `pull_up_subqueries_recurse()`). So I think your explanation is correct.